# VB.NET & SQL, Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add some buttons to my form with database information attached to them, to change their name, colour, etc.

I get this error: **MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()'** every time i try to read from the databse and add to my buttons.

Here's my code:

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT ProjectName, CompletedStatus, Startdate FROM projects WHERE inGroup = @currentgroup AND StartDate = " & Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        Dim reader
        With cmd
            .Connection.Open()
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentgroup", c.getmembergroup)
            reader = .ExecuteReader
        End With
        For i = 1 To count
            reader.read
            Dim b As New Button
            With b
                    .Text = reader.item("ProjectName")
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(b)
        Next
```

This issue happens both when reader.read is inside and outside of the For loop.

Here, count is a variable with the number of buttons to be made, It has already been tested and I know that it does what it's supposed to.

I've made sure that the names in my SQL match the names in my database, and the data types are correct.

The 'cn' variable where cmd is declared is just my connection, I left it out as it didn't seem relevant. The connection is valid and open.

Thanks in advance, and If you need any more info, please let me know, I'm new here so am never sure whether I've given enough.

Comment: `While reader.Read() dim b As New Button() with { .Text  = reader("ProjectName") } ... End While`. Pass the Date as Parameter, too. Is `Startdate` a string data Type? Possibly, use `Parameters.Add()` instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue()`. You should also declare and dispose of the Connection in the same procedure. Same for Command and DataReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Public Sub GetData(ByVal currentGroup As String, ByVal startDate As DateTime)

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ProjectName, CompletedStatus, Startdate FROM projects WHERE inGroup = @currentgroup AND StartDate = @startdate"

    Using con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionStr)

        'open 
        con.Open()

        Using cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

            Dim paramCurrentGroup As New MySqlParameter
            With paramCurrentGroup
                .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.String
                .ParameterName = "@currentgroup"
                .Value = currentGroup
            End With

            'add parameter
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCurrentGroup)

            Dim paramStartDate As New MySqlParameter
            With paramStartDate
                .MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.DateTime
                .ParameterName = "@startDate"
                .Value = startDate
            End With

            'add parameter
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramStartDate)

            Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                While reader.Read()
                    Dim projectName As String = reader.Item("ProjectName")
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("projectName: " & projectName)

                    Dim b As New Button
                    With b
                        .Text = projectName
                    End With

                    Me.Controls.Add(b)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

**Resources**:

- [Using Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)